# After implementing to office 365 able to login but getting Bad Request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, office365

We have implemented Office 365 Azure AD authentication for our application. However, after office 365 authentication, it is going in continuous loop till it throws an errors "Bad Request"

Comment: This happens to me on occasion too. First suggestion I found was 'use HTTPS instead of HTTP' when typing the address into the browser. Second suggestion I found was a code change, which I'll try and track down.

Comment: i am already using HTTPS instead of HTTP, even publishing the code with HTTPS since Office 365 only work for HTTPS.

Comment: Jusy saying... when you type the address in to actually access your application, make sure you enter https, not http

Comment: yes that what i am doing while accessing application.

Comment: Some links to consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169635/azure-infinite-redirect-loop-in-chrome https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/219 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bf7358da-0f7b-4ae9-b37b-0713b03041fc/infinite-loop-when-configuring-azure-active-directory-as-an-identity-provider?forum=sharepointgeneral https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94cfe1b5-15c8-420e-92ce-93c90cd7246f/aad-authentication-infinite-loop?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid we will try it out the solutions you provided and update you accordingly Thanks!!!.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver this link provide the solution in our case, could you put this in the "answer your question" part, so that i will select your answer as acceptance and you will be avail for bounty Thanks!!.

Comment: Oh! I'm pleased this solved your issue. I don't know if I really deserve a bounty for it - I just googled it! I will put a explanation and let the community decide if I am deserving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this solved issue:

https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver

Taken verbatim from the site:

> There is a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web. The
>   one that is being used when running Owin applications on IIS. Which is
>   what probably 99% of us do, if we're using the new Owin-based
>   authentication handling with ASP.NET MVC5.
>
> The bug makes cookies set by Owin mysteriously disappear on some
>   occasions.
>
> This middleware is a fix for that bug. Simple add it before any cookie
>   handling middleware and it will preserve the authentication cookies.

The process I followed, which appears to work so far is:

1. Using Project / Manage NuGet properties, add Kentor.OwinCookieSaver
2. In `Startup.Auth.cs`, inside `public partial class Startup`, before `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());`, add `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();`

abridged code sample

```
  public partial class Startup
  {
    // LOTS OF STUFF
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

UPDATE:

After this change the issue still exists

Comment: I really don't think I should accept this.. because I have exactly the same problem but I don't actually understand how to implement this. Instead I implemented this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser

Comment: Nope that implementation (Setting a cookie before authorisation) did not fix it either. I can't believe this authorisation system is so unreliable!

Comment: Yes that was my first suggestion. I'm going to have to work out how to include this code

Comment: This middleware is a fix for that bug. Simple add it before any cookie handling middleware and it will preserve the authentication cookies.
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

Comment: So I have the template code that is generated when you pick "Organizational Accounts" when you create the project. It creates a bunch of boilerplate code (in `Startup.Auth.cs` and `AccountController.cs` . I don't know which parts of this code are 'cookie handling middleware'/ Based on the github guide I found the existing line `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());` and put `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` before it. If this works I will edit my answer (a guess really) and add more detailed info